# How to merge two arrays using a property?

Tags: javascript

I want to create an (output) array of objects from one or multiple other (input) arrays.

For two input arrays defined as:

```js
var array1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'a2'},
    { id: 3, name: 'a3'},
    { id: 4, name: 'a4'},
    { id: 5, name: 'a5'},
];

var array2 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { data: 'we' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: { data: 'dfd' } },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { data: 'vbf' } },
];
```

...the resulting (output) array should be:

```js
var newarray = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { data: 'we' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: { data: 'dfd' } },
    { id: 3, name: 'a3', sub: {}},
    { id: 4, name: 'a4', sub: {}},
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { data: 'vbf' } },
];
```

I have tried the following but there is a mistake there somewhere:

```js
var newarray = [];
var oArray = {};
for(var i = 0; i <= array1.length;) {
    for(var j = 0; j <= array2.length; j++) {
        if(array1[i].id === array2[j].id) {
            oArray = {
                "id":  array1[i].id,
                 "name": array1[i].name,
                 "sub": array1[i].sub 
            };
            newarray.push(oArray);
            i++;
            break;
        } else {  
            oArray = {
                    "id":  array1[i].id,
                     "name": array1[i].name,
                     "sub": array1[i].sub 
                };
                newarray.push(oArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and how is `newarray` defined for your last snippet of code?

Comment: The operation you are looking for is abstractly known as a "join". You are essentially *joining" two input arrays on some predicate, in your case matching `id` values, to produce your desired output array. Specifically, it's called a "left [outer] join" as you join elements in the "left" array (`array1`) with corresponding elements in the "right" array (`array2`) or "empty" elements like `{ sub: {} }` when there is no corresponding element in the "right" array.

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't want to make `oArray` a local variable? If `oArray` isn't declared prior to assigning `oArray`, it is assumed to be a property of the global object (in a Web browser that's typically `window`) and as such will have the lifetime matching that of the global object (in a Web browser the page running the script). That's not what you usually want.

Comment: yes, i declared oArray before the loop starts and updated the snippet

Comment: @moor, Is this your expectation https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/PoKqEEJ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldreally make sure that the index limits for your loops are correct. `<=length` will cause a problem in any array.

Also, I would suggest first pushing into the array from `array1`, and then in the inner loop searching in the array to find matching id from `array1`. And simply updating.

```js
var array1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'a2'},
    { id: 3, name: 'a3'},
    { id: 4, name: 'a4'},
    { id: 5, name: 'a5'},
];

var array2 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { data: 'we' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: { data: 'dfd' } },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { data: 'vbf' } },
];

var newarray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length;i++) {            
   let oArray = {
       "id":  array1[i].id,
       "name": array1[i].name,
       "sub": {} 
   };
   newarray.push(oArray);
   for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
       if(array1[i].id === array2[j].id) {
           let found = newarray.find(x => x.id === array2[j].id);
           if(found) found.sub =array2[j].sub;
        } 
    }
}
console.log(newarray);
```

`let found = newarray.find(x => x.id === array2[j].id);`

[`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is used to find and return something on the array based on the specific condition. If the inner function returns true for any array index, the element at that index is returned. In our condition, we check to match the `id` and return based on that. So `found` is finally the found item based on condition. That is why only if it exists, we are accessing its property. If not found, found becomes `undefined`.

Above arrow function could well be written as:

`let found = newarray.find(function (x) { return (x.id === array2[j].id) });`

There are a lot of other ways to do it, but this one is closest to your approach and improves upon it.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what this line is doing , this doing magic. Also what => means.. it's like a reference?       
let found = newarray.find(x => x.id === array2[j].id);

Comment: It is an implementation of find(). Check edit. Hope it helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` to go over the array and `find` to find the corresponding item and then merge them how you like.

```js
const array1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'a2'},
    { id: 3, name: 'a3'},
    { id: 4, name: 'a4'},
    { id: 5, name: 'a5'},
];

const array2 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { data: 'we' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: { data: 'dfd' } },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { data: 'vbf' } },
];

const outcome = array1.map((x) => {
  const corresponding = array2.find((y) => y.name === x.name);
  return { ...x, sub: corresponding ? corresponding.sub : {} }
});

console.log(outcome);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a map function instead of a for-loop.
Here is my solution :

```js
var array1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'a2'},
    { id: 3, name: 'a3'},
    { id: 4, name: 'a4'},
    { id: 5, name: 'a5'},
];

var array2 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { data: 'we' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: { data: 'dfd' } },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { data: 'vbf' } },
];



let noSubs = array1.filter(el => ! array2.map(element => element.id).includes(el.id));
let newArray = noSubs.concat(array2);
console.log(newArray);
```